# When to use a java bean?

Tags: java, javabeans

i am learning about java beans but i want to know when one needs to use them. when to avoid them? what if the java source code is only used in one place in an application - is creating a bean for it not the way to go?

Comment: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it)

Comment: [This may help as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)

Comment: you'll need it when you need it, it all depends on the design and possible future use. it may be used only once in an application, yet someday other application might use it more than once, etc.

Comment: these don't help which is why i'm asking. i read that already but i wanted to hear something from a programmers perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most purpose, you will not need to care about the Java Beans, and you can just define classes as you see fit.

Sometimes you will be working with a framework, such as Spring, that will expect to interact with the getters, setters, and no-arg constructor that characterize a Java Bean.

By itself, the Java Bean specification is of very little relevance.

Comment: thank you. hence my confusion of a good situation when to use them. so i am trying to communicate from js to java. does that always require a java bean? when is a bad time to use it for that? is there a simpler way to go for most people? like, if someone asked me about what is a good language to use for embedded work i would say one usually wants to steer away from java because of.....c is better because of....

Comment: If you are trying to convert JSON to Java, there are many libraries that can help you, such as Jackson. Here is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/